# Context Senstive CSS Style

Tags: css, inheritance, overriding

I am having trouble specifying specific styles in my .css file.  I want h1 to have a context sensitive style based upon the div its in

I'm also trying to avoid the use/overuse of !important and taging each instance with a #id.  If I have to use !important or #id for each style I figure it might as well be done in line.  In short I want different styles based upon the tag a tag is in.

So...given class="A" and class="B"

If a tag like  is in a div with class="A" then I want it to have A’s  style regardless if a class="B" defines it differently.

This code would work until B is placed after A in the .css file.  Then B wins the style war.

```
<div class="A">
                <h1>some text right aligned</h1>
                <p> some text left aligned</p>
</div>


.A
{
   some styles
}

.A h1
{
     text-align: right;
}

.A p
{
    text-align: left;
}
```

---

This destroys the above

```
.B
{
    some styles
}

.B h1, p
{
   text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because of .B h1, p

this specifies all Ps not Ps related to .B class and because .B is last to be declared it overrides previous stylings.

here's how to do it:

```
<div class="a">
    <h1>right-aligned text</h1>
    <p>left-aligned text</p>
</div>

<div class="b">
    <h1>center-aligned text</h1>
    <p>center-aligned text</p>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.a h1 { text-align: right; }
.a. p { text-align: left; }
.b h1, .b p { text-align: center; }
```

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uadkrj9u/

Answer (score 1):

The only clash I'm seeing with your code, is that the 'p' tag is restyled at the bottom. Having the comma there means it's now unrelated to '.B', and will be restyled as it's placement follows on from '.A p'. So you'd need:

```
.B h1, .B p
{
text-align: center;
}
```

To make sure the

isn't affected by another class. That would be the only thing the lower code 'destroys'.

Comment: Relating them properly fixed it!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends by [Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) concept.

You can solve this problem, for example, appending `!important` after each property defined as descendant of `.A`

```
.A
{
   some styles !important
}

.A h1
{
     text-align: right !important;
}

.A p
{
    text-align: left !important;
}
```

or in alternative, adding one more css class on the container DIV and make .A descendants rules more specific thanks to this additional class.

```
<div class="high A">
     <h1>some text right aligned</h1>
     <p> some text left aligned</p>
</div>


.high.A
{
   some styles
}

.high.A h1
{
     text-align: right;
}

.high.A p
{
    text-align: left;
}


.B
{
    some styles
}

.B h1, p
{
   text-align: center;
}
```

In this way, rules defined for `.A` class are more specific than those defined on `.B`

Comment: Thanks for all the quick help.  I have it fixed ensuring the styles are related properly

Answer (score 0):

Your quotation marks are messed up and are not being rendered in by my browser.  Technically none of your styles work from the code that you've given me.  Otherwise they would, despite B existing in the stylesheet because HTML/CSS favors the most specific styles for elements.

```
<div class=”A”>
<div class="A">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8gha671d/

People in the other answers are saying that P might cause an issue, but because you already have `.A p {}`, the more general `p {}` will not override it because it is less specific.

Comment: Apologies for using the wrong quotes int he example. It was a cut and paste from Outlook. I fixed it in the example

Answer (score 0):

You can also add specificity by putting the element in a parent div with a specific class. More specificity will override the style without needing to use `!important` or using IDs (though there's nothing wrong with this approach unless you need to use more than one)

```
<style>
    .parent-div .A {
        ...
    }
</style>

<div class="parent-div">
    <div class=”A”>
                <h1>some text right aligned</h1>
                <p> some text left aligned</p>
    </div>
<div>
```